# How to use one back button to return to previous view (Multiple views route to this view)

Tags: ios, swift

**Description of my program**

Hello! Essentially, the program i am making uses several views to present questions to the user,collect the answer (and sometimes a picture relating to it) and the continue to the next view, which also contains a question. Though i am sure that is not the most efficient way whatsoever (and feel free to comment an optimized solution), it is how i am doing it thus far.

**The Problem**

The issue that i am running into is that i have a "notes" button on each of the views that will route them to a view called "Notes", which allows them to take a picture and make comments on the pictures. I would like to be able to return to whatever view i was on last, whether it is the first, second, or third.

*Note that i haven't done any graphical work on the view :)*

[image]

**The Code**

Though this is almost 100% not needed in this instance, here is the code i have for my "Notes" view:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class notesCamera: UIViewController,
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
@IBAction func photoLibraryAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker,animated:true, completion:nil)





}
@IBAction func cameraAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .camera
    present(picker,animated:true, completion:nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as? UIImage;dismiss(animated: true,completion:nil)
   }

}
```

Comment: if your using a navigation controller you could use `poptorootcontroller` to go back to your `root` (or something similar)

Comment: I am not using a navigation controller as of now. Would integrating one be easy seeing as i have a large amount of views on my storyboard?

Comment: not really, in your case you would treat the view controller you want to go back to as your `root controller`. if your using storyboard I THINK this is as simple as dragging in a navigation controller

Comment: there are some other ways though if you don't want to do this. I just  suggested that way because it is fairly common way to solve this problem. You can use the `ViewControllers` which is an array of all your controllers and navigate about those in the array

Comment: I am open to all suggestions. I like to have multiple options, so i'd love to here some others. Thank you for responding, by the way!

Comment: @panthor314, could you potentially elaborate on the ViewControllers array. I hate to be a bother, but i am quite the noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Storyboards are for.  If I were designing something like this, it would look (generally) like this:

[image: Storyboard]

My main View controller has two buttons.  Each button has a "Show" Segue.  The top button goes to the top View Controller.  The Botton button goes to the "Notes" View Controller directly.  The button on the Top View Controller also goes to the Notes View Controller.

The best part of this route is that no coding is required, and the "Back" button is there automatically.

If you want to see it, here's the project.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjem16mr4cyxpf3/VCPushPop.zip?dl=1

Comment: Would this work if i had, say, 6 views all connected to one "Notes" view. That's my current problem.

Comment: If you use storyboards and segues it will work with 100 all pointing at notes.  The idea is the encapsulate Notes in a View Controller and push and pop that controller on and off the stack as needed.  You can use prepareForSegue to pass data between the VCs as needed.